# How do I view of commit history of file in different branch without checking out that branch?

Tags: git

Is there any way I can force "git log " to read commit history from different branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
git whatchanged branch filename
```

to get an overview of all the commits in which the file was changed in that branch. And

```
git whatchanged -p branch filename
```

will give you detailed diffs of that file for each commit.

Answer (score 3):

Just type "git log branchname -- filename".

Comment: @Prafulla: What do you mean? Did it produce no output? Did it produce output with the log from a different branch? Did it give an error message?

Comment: I tried "git log <brname> -- <file path>", It did not show all commits from <brname>. But it showed all commits from current branch which mentions the word "<brname>".

Comment: Output of `git log` is similar to that of `git whatchanged` (given in [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12650003/571168)). Snippets from the `git-whatchanged` man page: 

`New users are encouraged to use git-log(1) instead. The whatchanged command is essentially the same as git-log(1) but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.

The command is kept primarily for historical reasons; fingers of many people who learned Git long before git log was invented by reading Linux kernel mailing list are trained to type it.`

Answer (score -1):

You can checkout a different branch without committing the branch you're currently in by using

```
git checkout <<branchname>> -f
```

I am fairly sure that this will not affect your current (uncommited) branch

Comment: I know that it would work with checking out. I am interested to know if there is any way to do it without checking out.